# building final project with node and visual studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I have written my server with node.js and visual studio ver 14. My server works well when i push the start button at the top menu of visual studio. but the Build solution option seems to do nothing. I have used the build option for other applications and my problem seems to be unique to Building for node.

here is the message i get:

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

any help to get my server compiled into it's own file would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not a VS user but what you expect by building your project. I mean what is your expected outcome?

Comment: i wanted my script to be compacted into its own executable file. so I could run it without VS installed or node installed.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a Javascript runtime environment. A Node.js project is a collection of scripts that perform a function (implement an REST API for example). The code is even independent of the Node.js runtime version and Javascript is a platform independent language. Therefore no matter what IDE you are using you shouldn't distribute your Node.js project as a platform specific binary.

I'm not sure of the VS specifics on this case but it shouldn't built a executable from your Node.js project.

Comment: OK thanks for the info. at least i know im not doing anything wrong!